# jQuery throws TypeError when triggering event on currently focused element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu with some buttons, where I can navigate through using the arrow keys and select a menu item by hitting return key. This works fine. When the first menu item is focused and I press the right arrow key, the focus jumps to the next menu item. Each menu item has a keydown event listener attached to it which handles the navigation.

The events listeners are bound to the menu items by attributes. A menu item's html looks like this:

```
<button 
    id="slbtn0"
    class="menu_button" 
    onkeydown="_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate(event)">
    <div class="menu_button_title">
        Menu item 1
    </div>
</button>
```

However, when I try to manually trigger the event, jQuery throws following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.event.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.extend.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
right @ remotecontrol.js:865
```

The event is triggered like this:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("keydown");
event.keyCode = _ACTION_TABLE.action.right[0]; // 39
event.which = _ACTION_TABLE.action.right[0]; // 39
$(document.activeElement).trigger(event);
```

I also tried to replace the last line with `$(':focus').trigger(event)`, but it makes no difference. The element I want to trigger the element on is focused, I have checked several times. The menu and its items are dynamically added, maybe this is a reason for the error?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate(event)` method? Firstly try to avoid event bubbling using e.g: `$(document.activeElement).triggerHandler(event);`

Comment: It's the function which handles the navigation. This function is never executed when triggering the event manually, checked that already. Changing to `.triggerHandler(event)` does not fix it. ;/

Comment: You should provide MCVE replicating your issue because imho it is quite unclear what you are trying to do/expecting. BTW, not clear how do you try to trigger event. Still not clear if `$(document.activeElement)` returns expected element or not. Etc...

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained my problem well above. Basically I just want to have the `onkeydown` callback function of the `#slbtn0` element called by triggering the `keydown` event manually. That's all.

Comment: But are you sure `_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate(event)` isn't called using your trigger snippet? This method expect a js event but you are passing jq event (i think but i'm not sure...), it could be the issue. Anyway, your issue could be something else which i'm not aware of. I'd try to use javascript dispatch method instead

Comment: Yes I'm sure it isn't called. The error message which I added to the question above is shown in console and that's all that happens. This method expect a js event ... Do you mean that the `onkeydown` attribute does not catch events triggered by jQuery?

Comment: Can you just answer question: `$(document.activeElement) returns expected element or no` **?**  `Do you mean that the onkeydown attribute does not catch events triggered by jQuery?` No i mean using inline attribute `onkeydown="_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate(event)"` event would be js event in method. Triggering it using jQuery, this event would be jQuery event object

Comment: Yes it returns expected element. Ok, but that wouldn't make a difference since the doNavigate() function is never called anyway..

Comment: It should be so maybe your debugging method is wrong or maybe i miss something else. So i'll stop guessing here because anyway you **must** provide MCVE.

Comment: No, it's never called for sure. The code crashes inside the jQuery source. Ok I'll try to build a MCVE, will be back in some minutes...

Comment: Well if you put a console.log() at top of `_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate()`, don't you see it?!

Comment: No it's never called!

Comment: So sorry but i'm out of idea :(

Comment: No problem, thank you for your effort!

Comment: I was just trying to make a small example where this issue is shown. I think the problem is that the `_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate(event)` method does not even exist at the time the `keydown` event is triggered, which makes absolutely no sense to me because it can be called whenever i want. Here is the example if you're interested: http://jsfiddle.net/1h4ry1ae/5/. The error message thrown is the same as in my question, except the different function name.

Comment: In your jsFiddle, you aren't declaring `glob.doNavigateMenu()` method on global scope but in setTimeout method callback. Javascript is function scoped. `The error message thrown is the same as in my question` but then you should have as error message that `_CONTENTPAGE.navigation.doNavigate()` is not a method (or former _CONTENTPAGE is undefined, ...). Your posted error message in opening post doesn't reflect it

Comment: Damn it.. I have absolutely no idea what's causing this error.

Comment: @A.Wolff fyi I found the problem. Soooomewhere in the code, there was an additional `keydown` listener set for these menu items, which was no function and caused this error.

Comment: That's regarding 'not defined function', right?! But is your former issue regarding error posted in opening question fixed?

Comment: This was the reason for the error message I mentioned in the question. Yes it's fixed now. :)